# Database design with multiple columns for reference or two columns with a reference type and id

Tags: database-design

I need a table for storing work items. A work item can be associated with one of many different types of existing entities in our database like a Person, Company etc. One way is to store an entity type and an entity id in two columns for the reference. This is something I have done before. The other way is to have multiple columns one for each type of entity.
In the first approach the applications has to maintain the integrity constraint in the association. The DB expert has preference on the 2nd approach as it can have FK constraint and also different data types for different entity ids if required.  Obviously for each row except one column all the others will have a null. Altering the table to add a new reference according to DB expert is not an issue and so is having many nulls.

At this point I have no major objections against this approach but still I would like to ask.
My question is, are there any good reason why the second approach should not be used.

Comment: What is the real-world relationship between a Person, a Company and WorkItem? Is the Person, the human that worked on the item? Is it the Person to whom the item was assigned? Is the Person that originated the item? Similarly with Company. Can both a Person and a Company be associated with the same WorkItem?

Comment: No there is no relationship between the Person and the Company. We deal with both and want to create a work item for the staff to do some piece of work. e.g. A WI may be change the person's address, another WI may be pay refund to a company etc. A Person and Company cannot have the same WI, a WI can only have one reference. We will also have User column for the WI for the staff that would be assigned to do the work.

Comment: @Pratik, Your question has 11 sentences. Only first two sentences describe the problem; the rest are your opinions,
things that you have done before, opinions of your DB expert, etc.
Are we really supposed to understand the problem (thing that you are trying to model) from only those two sentences?

Answer (score 0):

what if 2 values are not null?

what if zero values are not null?

You will need to add business logic to properly enforce the constraint either way.

The only benefit for additional columns is the default DB level constraint of FK definition.
The drawbacks are the same as drawbacks for all denormalization.

I would avoid having to change my schema for new data conditions, go with option one, create the proper business logic in a trigger to enforce the constraints.

my 2 cents

also:

consider that a work item may at some point wish to be associated with more than one of the same type of other entity (like person).

you have neglected another option, which is to create a new associative table linking the work_item to the person (or multiple - perhaps with role and status etc..)  and another for work_item to org.. etc.  this way, you can enforce the FK constraints on this middle table and have a good place for your business logic as well.

Comment: Two or more values are not null can be enforced by check constraint. Zero values are not null is allowed as a WI can be created with no reference and modified later to add a reference.